# Compiling TagLib into Qt C++ Project on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, taglib

I am currently trying to make the move from C# and break free from my platform boundaries by using Qt / C++.

I was using TagLibSharp in my old project, but I'm now trying to use the original C++ source found here:

http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html

I am in a world of hurt trying to compile this into my application. Most of this Linux based C++ is gibberish to me and I don't know how to properly include this library into my project with Qt. I'm using Qt Creator for the bulk of my work (everything I possibly can).

Can anyone please point me to some helpful tutorial or guides? Anything to help me understand what I am even doing with this source would be greatly appreciated. I have a very thorough understanding of C# and Windows programming, but I don't exactly have a good handle on what I'm doing with these types of open source projects.

Thanks!

**EDIT - THE ANSWER IS HERE**
I decided to post another question that was a bit more refined for it.

[Compiling static TagLib 1.6.3 libraries for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878883/compiling-static-taglib-1-6-3-libraries-for-windows)

***Some older edits...***

I now have TagLib compiled with Qt, but am running into "Undefined reference" errors.

***.pro**

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../$${TARGET}/taglib-win32
LIBS += -L"..\\$${TARGET}\\taglib-win32"
LIBS += -llibtag #It seems to want this to be a *.dll, not a *.a?
DEFINES += TAGLIB_NO_CONFIG
```

***.cpp**

```
#include <tag.h>
#include <fileref.h>
...
//None of these work, even though they are similar to examples given in TagLib source.
TagLib::FileRef f("03.flac");
TagLib::String test = f.tag()->album();
TagLib::FileName *n = new TagLib::FileName("test");
TagLib::FileRef *f = new TagLib::FileRef();
```

Here are some examples of the exact errors:

```
./debug\mythread.o:C:\Users\jocull\Documents\My Dropbox\Code\QT\QtTrayTime-build-desktop/../QtTrayTime/mythread.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefC1ENS_8FileNameEbNS_15AudioProperties9ReadStyleE' 
./debug\mythread.o:C:\Users\jocull\Documents\My Dropbox\Code\QT\QtTrayTime-build-desktop/../QtTrayTime/mythread.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK6TagLib7FileRef3tagEv' 
./debug\mythread.o:C:\Users\jocull\Documents\My Dropbox\Code\QT\QtTrayTime-build-desktop/../QtTrayTime/mythread.cpp:42: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib6StringD1Ev' 
./debug\mythread.o:C:\Users\jocull\Documents\My Dropbox\Code\QT\QtTrayTime-build-desktop/../QtTrayTime/mythread.cpp:42: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Command line steps using g++ (Mac/Linux)**

1. ./configure --enable-shared=false --enable-static=true
2. make
3. ??? No *.a or *.lib files created

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to C++ programming there are several issues you have to grasp to accomplish your task:

- Source files (`*.cpp`) contain the actual source code, while header files (`*.h`) just declare what's inside a source file. You have to include all headers in your source files that use classes/functions/variables from other source files.
- You need to understand how the preprocessor works. AFAIK C# does not have one. The wikipedia article should give you a good overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor
- Assuming you want to use TagLib as a dynamic library you have to create a Qt project for just building TagLib as a .dll (.pro file directives `TEMPLATE=lib`, `CONFIG+=dll`)
- If you want to create a dynamic library out of a source files you have to mark the functions you want to use later as exportable. In TagLib this is done by defining the preprocessor macro `MAKE_TAGLIB_LIB` (in your taglib .pro file: `DEFINES+=MAKE_TAGLIB_LIB`)
- Then you have to build the dynamic library (in your pro file: `TEMPLATE=lib`, then adding all sources and headers of taglib). When you use gcc this will result in two files `TagLib.dll` and `libTagLib.a`.
- When building your application you have to include the header files of TagLib in your source and tell the compiler about the library (in your .pro file: `LIBS+=libTagLib.a`)
- In your code you simply include the header file from your library. Let's say you want to use `TagLib::Tag` in your source file, then you must `#include <taglib/tag.h>`; You also have to tell the compiler (to be precise: the preprocessor) where it can find the `taglib` directory. In your .pro file you do this by adding `INCLUDEPATH+=/path/to/taglib`.

These are the *big points* and are not an in-depth explanation of what you have to do. Please ask more detailed questions if you have a problem when realizing this points.

For more information look at the qmake manual: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand h/cpp and I mostly get the preprocessor (I have some Obj-C experience).

TagLib actually comes with a *.pro file, and after a little tweaking I got it to compile. (It had a few errors, but I think it was config related.) Your recommended config is a bit different, but I think it could be more correct for Windows.

Anyways, I was able to produce a libTagLib.a and I added it to my *.pro file. However I'm unsure how to then reference this file in my code. Do you have any additional details on how to use external libraries in Qt's C++?

Comment: Do I have to have the *.h files available as well as the *.lib? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of a compiled library?

Comment: Actually I have a *.a, not *.lib.

Comment: Have have an .a file: Perfect. That's what gcc needs.

Comment: A .h file just declares class and methods, not how they are implemented. So, yes, you need them and you need to #include them. No, that does not defeat the purpose of a compiled library, since no "productive" code is contained in them.

Comment: Ok, this is all good to know. I think I am really close with this. I have compiled TagLib with Qt Creator into libTagLib.a (in release mode) and included the lib and include paths in my *.pro. I will edit my question to post what I currently have. However now my problem is that when I actually try to use anything, the compiler tells me I have an undefined reference to a garbled up name. I assume this means that it can't find the library that I specified? I'm fairly sure I have it written correctly.

Comment: Yes, the linker can't find the library. Please check your `LIBS+=...` path. It must contain the path to libTagLib.a also!

Comment: Be sure to compile TagLib with `DEFINES+=MAKE_TAGLIB_LIB`

Comment: I'm fairly certain the LIBS += is correct, because if I change it then the compiler complains that it can't find the file. I tried recompiling with DEFINES+=MAKE_TAGLIB_LIB but it's still giving me the same errors. I'm about out of ideas. Is there a specific compiler that I have to do this with? Am I missing a configure step?

Comment: I've tried doing this on Mac and Linux... but I get no *.a files out of my compiles. I will post my steps above in the original question. I'm not sure how to define MAKE_TAGLIB_LIB when I am doing this with the command line. Ideas?

Comment: I've noticed that if I use a *.dll (since I am on Windows primarily) the compiler seems to complain less about my LIBS. Per the recommendation of a few forums I've read, I switched my LIB += include. I will edit it above.

Comment: OK more updates... I *WAS* able to compile and use taglib on MacOSX! In that case, I compiled it in release mode with Qt Creator from the provided *.pro file. No issues. Set the INCLUDEPATH += and the LIB += to the *.a and it worked. Great! Windows is a different story...

Comment: Windows throws tons of DLL reference warnings and even a few errors when compiling with Qt Creator (I think it uses mingw32-make and mingw32-g++??). If I comment a couple lines out I can get it to compile, but the *.a files never work. It always complains about undefined references to things like '_imp___ZNK6TagLib7FileRef6isNullEv'. I can compile with no errors or warnings if I run the configure with MSYS, use CMAKE to create the makefiles (specified for for mingw32-make), and then make them with mingw32-make. This *.a is about 1MB larger, but has the same undefined issues...

Comment: I read on another forum somewhere that you should define ENABLE_STATIC=ON when compiling tagLib and you want the end-result to be static. I haven't noticed a difference on my Windows builds. Incidentally, how are you supposed to define these variables when running './configure' or 'make'?

Comment: This is getting complicated. I've tried 100 more things, so I just broke this off into a more specific question now that I halfway know what I'm talking about... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878883/compiling-static-taglib-1-6-3-libraries-for-windows