# Compiling static TagLib 1.6.3 libraries for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, taglib

I am having a super hard time compiling and using TagLib 1.6.3 in my Qt project. I've tried everything I can think of. TagLib claims that it is supported through CMake but I'm not having any luck. Furthermore, I'm confused about what kinds of files I even need for my Qt libs!

I've built *.a files, *.lib, and *.dll. From what I understand thus far... I believe that since I'm working in Windows *.lib is what I want. No matter what I do, I always end up with "undefined references" to any TagLib functions I try to use when I try to compile my Qt project. I have tried MinGW32, MSYS, Visual Studio 2008, and even cross-compiling for Windows on Linux. All turning up nothing.

What makes even less sense to me is that if I compile the same TagLib source with Qt on Mac (g++ I think?) it works fine! Somewhere in my Windows compilation procedures I have to be going wrong. I have been smacking my face on my desk for probably about 30 (on and off) hours trying to figure this out.

Since Qt uses minGW must I compile TagLib with the same compiler?

If I compile *.lib's with Visual Studio are they not compatible?

Are *.a libraries even usable in Windows? (assuming minGW)

I'm still trying to get a handle on this C++ stuff, but after reading countless forum threads and other questions I'm still coming up short. Here is what I have been working with in CMake currently...

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DENABLE_STATIC=ON -DHAVE_ZLIB=0 -DWITH_MP4=1 -DMAKE_TAGLIB_LIB=1
cmake --build ./
```

This generates a single *.a file of ~2MB in size. The working library on Mac was ~3MB, and the *.lib from Visual Studio was ~4MB in Release mode. Please someone save me from this C++ cross platform command line madness because I am at my wit's end. I would probably even pay you to just compiling me some %!$#&ing libraries. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Mac works for you, I'm just talking about Win32.

Ok, this are my Taglib.pro and an excerpt of my project.pro: https://gist.github.com/449ea81ce92f52399f41. Check them out. My Taglib may be a bit outdated, so take care, some files you may have could be missing there. Also take care of the relative paths. They are all relative to the .pro file.

I just ran `cmake .` inside the taglib directory. This should result in a `config.h` and a `taglib_config.h`

You definitly only need the `libTaglib.a` when you use QtCreator and mingw-gcc. *.lib are MSVC specific!

Comment: This is great information to have, thanks. In the past I have been smashing all the *.h files into one directory for my INCLUDEPATH to make it easier to manage. Is this incorrect? Also I haven't been including DEPENDPATH because I didn't know I needed it.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if you need DEPENDPATH, but it doesn't hurt either. Since TagLib itself relies on proper Include Paths smashing all .h files into one directory is not a good idea but not the source of your linker problem!

Comment: Im not 100% sure about this: You're compiling TagLib as a shared library, but your linker complains about some symbols. Make sure your linker does know that the symbols from TagLib are _dynamically_ loaded, not _statically_! Make sure you **don't** have defined `TAGLIB_STATIC` **nor** `MAKE_TAGLIB_LIB` when compiling your program. Read `taglib_export.h` carefully as this file is the pivotal point for exporting or importing symbols.

Comment: Just so I understand this, I **do** want to compile TagLib statically, but when I am compiling my program TagLib is now considered a **shared** resource. Is that correct?

Comment: Do you have any efficient methods that you use to export all the *.h files in their current directory structures? It's a mess the way it is currently.

Comment: When you create a .dll and a .a file you create a **shared** resource. To link TagLib statically (ie. directly) into your binary, just add TagLib's sources to your .pro file (with `SOURCES`) and define `TAGLIB_STATIC`.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies, thanks. In that case, I'm currently working with a **shared** TagLib build. I actually got it to build with Qt (finally) and I have it configured like you showed. I have everything compiling with no errors, but once I run I get an error immediately: QtTrayTime.exe exited with code -1073741515 ... From the Googling I've done I'm assuming this means that I did something wrong with linking my shared library. I made a Gist of what I have currently: http://gist.github.com/615451

Comment: Glad to hear that. Try to copy `TagLib.dll` into the same directory as your QtTrayTime.exe.

Comment: AHHHH IT WORKS! You are the best man, thanks so much for all of your help. This has been the bane of my existence for days. I should have thought of that (it's what you have to do in C#) but this C++ stuff is throwing me for a loop pretty hard. Can you explain to me why since we define things like win32:LIBS += why I have to manually copy the DLL? Is the LIBS += just for the compiler's use, but I have to manually copy the DLL for the .exe's use? Why isn't it like this on Mac?

Comment: Thanks to your help I was also able to statically compile the TagLib source files into my project. It was as easy as adding the *.h and *.cpp files to my project and adding DEFINES += TAGLIB_STATIC=1. I also copied over the FRAMEWORK_HEADERS and QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA for Mac from the original TagLib *.pro. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This  [blog post](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-compile-taglib-on-windows/) details the whole process described in this thread.

The blog post author, Joel, was nice enough to provide the [binaries of taglib 3.6.3](http://www.joelverhagen.com/projects/music-tagger/taglib-release.zip) compiled for windows.

Answer (score 1):

I use cmake for my projects.Here is my cmake file for a media player I made that uses taglib.  I installed taglib to /usr/local/  (this way I don't have to change anything when I compile in Linux).  The important parts have an arrow.

```
project(qtmu3)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
-> find_library(TAGLIB_LIB tag PATH /usr/local/lib/)
set(QT_USE_PHONON TRUE)
set(QTMU_SRCS main.cpp mainwindow.cpp WidgetMarqueeLabel.cpp single_application.cpp)
set(QTMU_MOC_HDRS mainwindow.h WidgetMarqueeLabel.h single_application.h)
set(QTMU_UI_FILES mainwindow.ui)
set(QTMU_RSRC_FILES myresources.qrc)
-> include_directories(/usr/local/include/taglib/)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-mwindows")
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
QT4_WRAP_UI( QTMU_UI_HDRS ${QTMU_UI_FILES})
QT4_WRAP_CPP( QTMU_MOC_SRCS ${QTMU_MOC_HDRS})
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QTMU_RSRC_SRCS ${QTMU_RSRC_FILES})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
ADD_EXECUTABLE(qtmu3 ${QTMU_SRCS} ${QTMU_MOC_SRCS} ${QTMU_RSRC_SRCS} ${QTMU_UI_HDRS})
-> TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(qtmu3 ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${TAGLIB_LIB})
```

The last one, just the ${TAGLIB_LIB} is important.
hope that helps someone.