# Using TagLib in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, static-libraries, taglib

**EDIT:** Yes, I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878883/compiling-static-taglib-1-6-3-libraries-for-windows). Unfortunately, it looks like the user ends up using MingW in the end.

---

I am on **Windows 7**, 64-bit. I downloaded the most recent version of the TagLib code from the SVN repository. I am using revision **1202935**.

I am trying to use TagLib in **Visual Studio 2010**. I have gotten TagLib to work with QtCreator/MingW, but I want to start learning the Windows API so I am starting from scratch in Visual Studio 2010 (C++ of course).

In VS2010, I have build zlib (both statically and dynamically) and TagLib with and without zlib (both statically and dynamically). In other words, I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work.

My ideal situation is that I use CMake to generate the VS2010 project files (there is an option for VS2010 64-bit. I **do not** choose this option) for TagLib. I would like them to be static libraries, so I enable ENABLE_STATIC, and I enable WITH_ASF, and WITH_MP4. I also direct TagLib to zlib using ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR and ZLIB_LIBRARY (I am linking to the zlib.lib file that I previously built using VS2010). Note, I am using the CMake GUI.

I then open up the generated project files in VS2010 and make three changes to the code so that it build in Visual Studio 2010 without error (*I put the fixes here for anyone else who had the same problem as I*).

**apefooter.cpp**  on line 192:

```
std::bitset<32> flags(static_cast<unsigned long long>(data.mid(20, 4).toUInt(false)));
```

**mpcproperties.cpp** on line 116:

```
std::bitset<32> flags = static_cast<unsigned long long>(d->data.mid(8, 4).toUInt(false));
```

**mpegheader.cpp** on line 171:

```
std::bitset<32> flags(static_cast<unsigned long long>(data.toUInt()));
```

I then make then comment out lines 436 and 437 in **mpegfile.cpp**, because [I think it's a bug](http://mail.kde.org/pipermail/taglib-devel/2010-December/001723.html).

```
// ID3v2Tag(true);
// ID3v1Tag(true);
```

I then build the project in Release mode. It builds just fine. No errors (although there are a bunch of warnings).

So I have generated **tag.lib**. I then created a test VS2010 project/solution to use TagLib.

This is the only line I use TagLib. Just a test, mind you.

```
TagLib::MPEG::File a("tests/other/blank.mp3");
```

- I added `TAGLIB_STATIC` to the preprocessor options (*Property Pages > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions*) for all configurations (both Release and Debug builds)
- I added every single darn header directory to *Property Pages > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories*
- And finally I added zlib.lib and tag.lib to the additional dependencies (*Property Pages > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies*) IN THAT ORDER

"Whew! What a hassle! Now let's see if it works?"

```
1>vs_taglib_test.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001A) "public: virtual __clrcall TagLib::MPEG::File::~File(void)" (??1File@MPEG@TagLib@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>vs_taglib_test.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001B) "public: __clrcall TagLib::MPEG::File::File(class TagLib::FileName,bool,enum TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle)" (??0File@MPEG@TagLib@@$$FQAM@VFileName@2@_NW4ReadStyle@AudioProperties@2@@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>vs_taglib_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __clrcall TagLib::MPEG::File::~File(void)" (??1File@MPEG@TagLib@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>vs_taglib_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall TagLib::MPEG::File::File(class TagLib::FileName,bool,enum TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle)" (??0File@MPEG@TagLib@@$$FQAM@VFileName@2@_NW4ReadStyle@AudioProperties@2@@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
```

Can someone else try out what I'm doing here and point out my mistake? I tried to provide enough information for y'all to see what's happening.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to build TagLib 1.7 using Visual Studio 2010.

My Steps

- Download zlib sources from
  http://zlib.net/
- Download zlib bins from
  http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/index.html
- Setup VC++ Directories to zlib source
  &  bins
- Download TagLib 1.7 from
  http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html
- Extract taglib-1.7 directory
- Use command prompt to run  - cmake -G "Visual Studio 10"  in taglib-1.7 directory
- Open & build taglib.sln
- .dll and lib files go to /taglib-1.7/taglib/Debug & /taglib-1.7/taglib/Release

Using the CMake gui throws up errors for ZLIB and adding the zlib directories and lib manually will generate a visual studio solution but it would not generate the .dll files (linking errors)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `__clrcall`.  You didn't mention that your project is C++/CLI but that's a very important detail.

People have [run into this with other libraries, like Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248111/error-linking-to-oci-libraries-from-vc).

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "taglib.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
```

to let Visual C++ know that taglib is native code.

Answer (score 0):

### define the macro "TAGLIB_STATIC" in your code!

example

#define TAGLIB_STATIC