# Common LNK 2019 - function declaration in header file - definition in source file

Tags: c++, linker, c++-cli

Considering it's a common issue, what could be the source of this error if one uses this file logic:

- Utils.h: declare `bool Dummy();`
- Utils.cpp: define `bool Dummy() {return true;}`
- ClassA.h : an irrelevant `class A { bool sheet; public: A(); };`
- ClassA.cpp: the irrelevant code:

  ```
   #include "Utils.h"
   #include "ClassA.h"
   A::A() { sheet = Dummy(); }
  ```

  *Note*: all header files contain the guard `#pragma once` macro.

The error: something like this

```
Error   2   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000B) "bool __clrcall Dummy(void)" 

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __clrcall Dummy(void)" .... in ClassA.obj
```

Comment: Are you sure `Utils.cpp` is not excluded from build?

Comment: Theoretically it shouldn't be excluded from the build, it's in a VS VC++2010 project and everything else works a-ok. Is there something that can go wrong in VC++ by default? I'm not using any external libs, dlls, nothing of the sort, so no extra folders to be added in the build properties.

Comment: Have you tried a complete rebuild from scratch?

Comment: Check out [error linking to oci libraries from vc++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248111/error-linking-to-oci-libraries-from-vc). Is it the same problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, what I did was to include it in a pure, native, unmanaged C++ project and it spat out the same error. So, when putting _function_ declaration in a header, how to properly build the project if their implementations are in separate cpp files? It's a noob question, but my google skills that usually don't suck failed me for an entire day already.. (I'm a noob in managed C++-CLI and it tends to puzzle me if something that works in pure C++ just won't work there). But this is also for native c++.. so, like they always say: "please help"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> bool **__clrcall** Dummy(void)

You are compiling the ClassA.cpp file with /clr in effect, generating managed code.  Your Dummy() function however was compiled without /clr, making the calling convention __cdecl.  The linker notices the discrepancy, it can't find the managed implementation for Dummy.

You must tell the compiler that Utils.cpp was built to native code.  Fix ClassA.cpp like this:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "Utils.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
#include "ClassA.h"
// etc...
```

Comment: Same thing. It's even the same for an unmanaged project. I simply add the `utils.h` and `utils.cpp` files with the `bool dummy();` function and use the `dummy` in another `.cpp` file of a certain class of that unmanaged project. So, I think it's not only because it's managed: I removed the `__clrcall` decorator and still the same.

Comment: You removed the __clrcall decorator??  From where?

Comment: sorry, in one of my trials.. I added it out of zealousness and thinking that it might at least throw another error.