# Taglib unresolved external issues (FileRef)

Tags: taglib, unresolved-external, externals

So I'm attempting to use taglib in a project I'm working on, and can not seem to get past a few unresolved externals. To start, I downloaded the latest taglib release from github, and proceeded to follow the answer given in [Using TagLib in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413949/using-taglib-in-visual-studio-2010). After building taglib, I proceeded to add the following paths to my VS10 include directories for my project: C:\code\libs\taglib; C:\code\libs\taglib\taglib; C:\code\libs\taglib\taglib\toolkit (note that my root directory for taglib was renamed simply to taglib).
After doing this I attempted to use the example in the getting started section of this page: http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib/api/
So I simply copied the first line of code, attempting to open up a FileRef:

```
TagLib::FileRef f("Latex Solar Beef.mp3");
```

With that line and none of the rest of the example in my code, VS2010 spits out the following unresolved external errors:

```
getFileInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall TagLib::FileRef::~FileRef(void)" (__imp_??1FileRef@TagLib@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl tagLibTest(void)" (?tagLibTest@@YAXXZ)
getFileInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall TagLib::FileRef::FileRef(class TagLib::FileName,bool,enum TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle)" (__imp_??0FileRef@TagLib@@QAE@VFileName@1@_NW4ReadStyle@AudioProperties@1@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl tagLibTest(void)" (?tagLibTest@@YAXXZ)
getFileInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall TagLib::FileName::FileName(char const *)" (__imp_??0FileName@TagLib@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl tagLibTest(void)" (?tagLibTest@@YAXXZ)
```

Things I've tried:

1. So I tried an empty constructor, just to see if I could at least get a void FileRef, and that does compile, but isn't really helpful.
2. Manually adding every single directory in the taglib folder to the include paths, this changed nothing.
3. Rebuilding multiple times from both the taglib site and github.

At this point I'm thinking it's likely a problem with the way I have my environment set up, but am not really sure what to post with regards to that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Are you telling VS somehow that it should link your program with TagLib?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved this by changing the Build Configuration of the TagLib VS Solution from Debug to Release.