# Error during compilation of Qt program with TagLib

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

I'm creating program in Qt that uses TagLib library. I have built TagLib with Visual Studio 12 compiler. Then I added it as "dynamic library" to my project. In my code I wrote `#include "tag.h"`and application was built succesfully. But when I decided to use `TagLib::FileRef` class, I can see errors
 
`undefined reference to '_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefC1Ev'` 
`undefined reference to '_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev'` 
`release/playlist1.o: bad reloc address 0x45 in section '.text$_ZN5QListI7QStringED1Ev[__ZN5QListI7QStringED1Ev]'` 
What I have to do?

Comment: Hi, did you link your lib to your app ? `LIBS += -L/*PATH_TO_MY_LIB*/ -lmylib`

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes that could lead to undefined reference, it's hard to solve your problem with only your information. Does the problem occur in a specific file or even in a simple main without any dependencies you can't use your lib ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling TagLib into Qt C++ Project on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860703/compiling-taglib-into-qt-c-project-on-windows)

Comment: To solve your problem, I'll recommend to take a look at http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-compile-taglib-on-windows/ and http://mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/build_windows_dependencies#taglib

Comment: @troyane I tried to solve my problem with these 2 tutorials. Unfortunately, compiler still shows me similar errors :(