# Taglib in a C++/Qt project on Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to compile a Qt project (Specifically [Liri Vinyl](http://github.com/liri-project/liri-vinyl)) on Windows 10. I've loaded the .pro file in Qt Creator but when I try to run I'm missing taglib.h. I've done some research and have finally ended up with a "libtaglib.a" file and a "tablib.dll" file but I can't figure out how to make Qt find them. I've tried several of the suggestions from [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860703/compiling-taglib-into-qt-c-project-on-windows) but to no avail.

Comment: What’s not found right now, the header (when compiling) or the lib (when linking)?

Comment: The header when compiling

Answer (score 0):

So basically all the development for Liri Vinyl has been done so far on Linux, so I hadn't even thought about possible issues on Windows.

I took a shot at getting it to compile and run on Windows 10 today, and while I had a few issues (attributed to the fact that I don't do development on Windows), I was able to get it all sorted out.  See below for exact instructions:

1. Download and install Qt5.5 (MinGW version) from [here](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.5/5.5.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.5.1.exe).
2. Download and install CMake from [here](https://cmake.org/).
3. Download TagLib 1.10, and compile for Windows using MinGW included in Qt.  For in depth instructions on how to do this, see the INSTALL file [here](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/blob/master/INSTALL.md).
   This is the step that I was getting stuck on for about an hour or so earlier. Finding this page provided the correct instructions for installing taglib.
4. Link in the .pro file.

   Your TagLib should be installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\taglib\ and have three subdirectories: bin, lib, include.

   Based on that, here's what you need to do:

   Make sure the .pro file contains these lines:

   ```
   # As far as I can tell, taglib needs to be statically linked on windows.      See readme for more info.
   win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += "C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/lib/libtag.dll.a"
   INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include"
   DEPENDPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include"
   ```

And then in Qt Creator, build for release.  When it builds, it will complain that it cannot find libtag.dll.  Go to TagLibs installation dir/bin (C:\Program Files (x86)\taglib\bin\libtag.dll) and copy libtag.dll from there into the liri vinyl build directory.  Then rebuild: you're good to go.

Ideally nobody will have to compile on windows in the future, once I can get some binary releases happening.  For now, though, these instructions should help you get it all set up.  Also, you will probably want to grab the latest from the master branch, as I have just fixed some issues with song urls on Windows.